# Memoria Dinámica (Uso de realloc)

Tags: c

Hola a toda la comunidad, estoy aprendiendo a programar con memoria dinámica y necesito realizar una funcion que me permita expandir la memoria dinámica de un arreglo.

Al comienzo se debe llenar el arreglo iniciando en 0, hasta n=1, después de eso el arreglo debe expandir su memoria en 5 y al mismo tiempo este debe de llenar los lugares que faltan, el resultado debería de imprimirse en pantalla, pero a la hora de ejecutar el programa no hace nada y se termina.

¡Gracias por la ayuda!

Estructura:

```
typedef struct{
    float i,r;
}Complejo;
```

Código principal:

```
int main(){
  int n=1;
  Complejo *nc1, *r1;
  nc1= (Complejo *)malloc(sizeof(Complejo)*n);
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
      nc1[i].i=i;
      nc1[i].r=i;
  }
  r1=masMemoria(nc1, 5);
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
      nc1[i].i=i;
      nc1[i].r=i;
  }
  for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
      printf("Real nc1: %f  Imaginario: %f\n", r1[i].r, r1[i].i);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Función:

```
Complejo *masMemoria(Complejo *nc, int x){
Complejo *aux;  
if(nc == NULL){
    nc=(Complejo *)malloc(sizeof(Complejo));
            if(nc==NULL){
                printf("Problemas al reservar memoria dinámica\n");
            }
}
else{
    aux=(Complejo *)realloc(nc, sizeof(Complejo)*x);
        if(aux!=NULL){
            nc=aux;
        }
        else{
            printf("Problemas al reservar memoria dinámica\n");
            return nc;
        }
}
return nc;
}
```

Comment: ¿Como lo usas? `mem=masMemoria(mem, 5);`

Comment: Ah, perdonen no especifique eso,  creía que lo había cambiado, x es la nueva longitud y nc es el arreglo al que se le va a expandir la memoria

Comment: Esto se nota. Pero lo que quiero decir es cómo estás llamándola: `mem=masMemoria(mem, 5)` ¿?

Comment: @sbrubes Sí, es de esa manera solo que en lugar de igualarla al mismo apuntador yo lo hice asi:  r1=masMemoria(nc1, k) ….. (Lamento que no este en formato de código como soy nuevo en la plataforma aun no he aprendido varias cosas..)

Comment: Edite tu pregunta y añade cómo estás usándola. Además ponga lo que esperas y *no pasa* con tu código.

Comment: @sbrubes Creo ya agregue lo necesario... bueno realmente es todo el código

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 6):

Aparte de lo comentado, date cuenta que no hace falta discriminar si `nc1` es nulo o no a la hora de decidir entre usar `malloc` y `realloc`. `realloc` te sirve para los dos casos por igual, tal y como indica en la [documentación](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/):

> In case that ptr is a null pointer, the function behaves like malloc, assigning a new block of size bytes and returning a pointer to its beginning.

Que viene a decir:

> Si *ptr* es un puntero nulo, la función se comportará igual que *malloc*, asignando un nuevo bloque de *size* bytes y devolviendo un puntero al inicio de dicho bloque.

Explicado con código, el ejemplo siguiente es equivalente al de tu función original, pero con la mitad de líneas y de complejidad:

```
Complejo *masMemoria(Complejo *nc, int x)
{
  Complejo *aux = (Complejo *)realloc(nc, sizeof(Complejo)*x);
  if(aux!=NULL)
  {
    nc=aux;
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Problemas al reservar memoria dinámica\n");
  }
  return nc;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> A la hora de ejecutar el programa no hace nada y se termina.

Esta es una descripción muy vaga del problema, que además no se ajusta a la realidad. [He probado tu código](https://wandbox.org/permlink/y9faLFI0zQjeR0e4) y me ha mostrado datos por pantalla:

> ```
> Real nc1: 0.000000  Imaginario: 0.000000
> Real nc1: 0.000000  Imaginario: 0.000000
> Real nc1: 0.000000  Imaginario: 0.000000
> Real nc1: 0.000000  Imaginario: 0.000000
> Real nc1: 0.000000  Imaginario: 0.000000
> ```

Procura ser más claro y conciso en tu pregunta.

---

A base de analizar tu código, deduzco que esperabas esta salida:

> ```
> Real nc1: 0.000000  Imaginario: 0.000000
> Real nc1: 1.000000  Imaginario: 1.000000
> Real nc1: 2.000000  Imaginario: 2.000000
> Real nc1: 3.000000  Imaginario: 3.000000
> Real nc1: 4.000000  Imaginario: 4.000000
> ```

Pero no se puede dar, porque en el bucle de rellenado de datos:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    nc1[i].i=i;
    nc1[i].r=i;
}
```

Recorres la formación<sup>1</sup> hasta la posición `n`, cuyo valor se establece a `1` al principio de `main` y no vuelve a cambiar en todo el programa. Por otro lado, reservas memoria sobre el puntero `nc1` pero después realojas memoria sobre `r1`, el puntero pasado a `masMemoria` no cambia porque lo pasas por copia (el cambio de valor del puntero no sale de la función).

"*Supongo*" que en realidad querías hacer esto:

```
int main(){
  int n = 1;
  Complejo *nc1; // <-- Solo un puntero
  nc1 = (Complejo *)malloc(sizeof(Complejo) * n);

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      nc1[i].i = i;
      nc1[i].r = i;
  }

  n = 5;                    // <-- Nuevo valor de n.
  nc1 = masMemoria(nc1, n); // Usamos n.

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) { // Ahora el bucle rellena toda la formación
      nc1[i].i = i;
      nc1[i].r = i;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      printf("Real nc1: %f  Imaginario: %f\n", nc1[i].r, nc1[i].i);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

En los bucles, deberías favorecer el preincremento frente al postincremento, salvo que tengas un motivo para no hacerlo (que rara vez será así). Lee [este artículo](https://vitaminacpp.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/leyenda-pre-y-post-incremento/) para más detalles.

El apelotonamiento también contribuye a que tu código sea difícil de seguir y comprender; en los años 90 teníamos pantallas de 80 caracteres de ancho y 25 líneas de alto, eso hacía necesario estrujar el código para que cupiera en pantalla la mayor cantidad posible; por suerte han pasado casi 30 años y ya no tenemos esa limitación.

También debes tener en cuenta que estás pidiendo memoria dinámica pero no la estás liberando, no olvides la llamada a `free` al finalizar el programa.

Para acabar, la elección de nombres de tus variables empeora más la situación, los nombres que son acrónimos o una sola letra aportan muy poca información sobre el dato manejado y para colmo hace más probable que dos variables diferentes tengan nombres parecidos y provoque confusión (como en tu bucle de pintado, que imprimes `nc1` en el texto pero usas el valor de `r1`).

Resolviendo los problemas mencionados, tu código podría parecerse a:

```
typedef struct{
    float imaginario, real;
} Complejo;

Complejo *masMemoria(Complejo *original, int cantidad) {
    Complejo *aux;

    if ((aux = (Complejo *)realloc(original, sizeof(Complejo) * cantidad))) {
        return aux;
    }

    printf("Problemas al reservar memoria dinámica\n");
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    int cantidad = 1;
    Complejo *datos = (Complejo *)malloc(sizeof(Complejo) * cantidad);

    for (int indice = 0; indice < cantidad; ++indice) {
        datos[indice].imaginario = indice;
        datos[indice].real = indice;
    }

    cantidad = 5;
    datos = masMemoria(datos, cantidad);

    for (int indice = 0; indice < cantidad; ++indice) {
        datos[indice].imaginario = indice;
        datos[indice].real = indice;
    }

    for (int indice = 0; indice < cantidad; ++indice) {
        printf("Real: %f  Imaginario: %f\n", datos[indice].real, datos[indice].imaginario);
    }

    free(datos);

    return 0;
}
```

---

1. También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.

Comment: Es una **mala solución a la que propone al final**, además de una grave **fuga de memoria**.

Comment: @sbrubes el código está sin duda mal, pero la fuga de memoria proviene del código original no de mi modificación. Sin embargo, los consejos son correctos.

Comment: Hablo de la tuya: en `datos = masMemoria(cantidad);`

Comment: Ya está corregido @sbrubes, hacía tiempo que me di cuenta de mi error pero me daba pereza corregir, pero tu intervención me ha animado a hacerlo, gracias :)

Comment: Ahora no compila

Comment: [Solucionados](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0poU5KEZapRxd1qP) los typo, errores de copypaste y despiestes, gracias @sbrubes

Answer (score 2):

Aquí está la manera de hacer lo que quieres (compreenda y execute):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    float i,r;
}Complejo;

Complejo *masMemoria(Complejo *nc, int x){
Complejo *aux;  
if(nc == NULL){
    nc=(Complejo *)malloc(sizeof(Complejo)*x);
            if(nc==NULL){
                printf("Problemas al reservar memoria dinámica\n");
            }
}
else{
    aux=(Complejo *)realloc(nc, sizeof(Complejo)*x);
        if(aux!=NULL){
            nc=aux;
        }
        else{
            printf("Problemas al reservar memoria dinámica\n");
            return nc;
        }
}
return nc;
}

int main(){
  int n=1;
  Complejo *nc1 = NULL;
  nc1= masMemoria(nc1, n);
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
      nc1[i].i=i;
      nc1[i].r=i;
  }
  n=5;
  nc1=masMemoria(nc1, n);
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
      nc1[i].i=i;
      nc1[i].r=i;
  }
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
      printf("Real nc1: %f  Imaginario: %f\n", nc1[i].r,nc1[i].i);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Cuando hiciste `r1=masMemoria(nc1, 5);`, `realloc` va ha alocarte una nueva posición de memoria para poner las 5 estruturas `Complejo`, y copiar el contenido que tenias en `nc1`. Hecho esto, este va liberar `nc1`.

Entonces cuando pasas en el `for`, y cambias el contenido en `nc1`, ya estás trabajando con una memória no más lista (lo que es muy mal):

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
   nc1[i].i=i;
   nc1[i].r=i;
}
```

Para hacer que tu código funcione solo esto ya bastaba:

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
   r1[i].i=i;
   r1[i].r=i;
}
```

Pero lo deje mejor para que `n` siempre contenga el tamaño.

Igual, tu no consideraba el tamaño (`x`) cuando asignaba memoria con `malloc` en tu función `masMemoria`.

Por ultimo, he suprimido `r1`, ya que `nc1` no será más valido quando reubicado, es mala práctica mantenerlo.

Comment: Falta un `free` al finalizar `main`.

Comment: No pasa nada.. No hay programa que quede con memoria sin executar.

Comment: Si pasa, como programadores tenemos la responsabilidad de hacernos cargo de los recursos del programa (es como si me dijeras que no pasa nada por tirar basura en la calle, ya pasará un barrendero a recogerla). La memoria no se *executa*, la memoria se usa.

Comment: ¿Estás a decirme que mi programa se queda con la memoria después de salir en el `return 0;`?

Comment: No, estoy diciendo que como programadores tenemos la responsabilidad de hacernos cargo de los recursos del programa.

Comment: Seguro tengo más lo que hacer.